# Access location on Realwear HMT

Tags: android, iot

The Realwear HMT device mentions that it supports Assisted GPS. The device does not have google play service installed. There are no samples available for GPS on their Github. 
How do I access the location on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the location services on the HMT-1 is done via the Location Manager, which is standard Android functionality. Implementation wise, it is accomplished exactly the same as any other Android device, the only difference comes when optimizing the application for voice control. The correct permissions must be added to the manifest, but Google Play Services is not required for GPS/AGPS to function.

On the HMT, go to My Programs>'Settings'>'Page Down'>'Location'>'Mode', then say 'High Accuracy'>'Agree' to select this mode.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager